# adding current function to child functions.php for editing

Tags: php, wordpress, function, parent-child

I am working on a client site that has two blocks of blog content (enclose in the article tags below) on the home page, and I need to move the title and date of the blocks to the end of them. I was able to move the title by moving this:

```
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

to the location I wanted in functions.php (shown below). However, I changed it in the parent file and I know that's a bad idea.

But I can't figure out which part of this code I'm supposed to copy and paste into my child functions.php file, and everything I try ends up giving me just a blank screen. I'm still learning PHP, so I'm not sure how to copy for correct syntax. (Sorry for copying so much code, just really confused.)

I'm also not sure which part of move for changing the location of the date (the date class is "post-meta").

Can someone help?

The site is [abundancepractice-building.flywheelsites.com](http://abundancepractice-building.flywheelsites.com).

```
add_shortcode( 'et_pb_blog', 'et_pb_blog' );
function et_pb_blog( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'module_id' => '',
        'module_class' => '',
        'fullwidth' => 'on',
        'posts_number' => 10,
        'include_categories' => '',
        'meta_date' => 'M j, Y',
        'show_thumbnail' => 'on',
        'show_content' => 'off',
        'show_author' => 'on',
        'show_date' => 'on',
        'show_categories' => 'on',
        'show_pagination' => 'on',
        'offset_number' => 0,
        'background_layout' => 'light',
        'show_more' => 'off',
    ), $atts
) );

global $paged;

$container_is_closed = false;

if ( 'on' !== $fullwidth ){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-masonry-3' );

    $background_layout = 'light';
}

$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => (int) $posts_number );

$et_paged = is_front_page() ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' );

if ( is_front_page() ) {
    $paged = $et_paged;
}

if ( '' !== $include_categories )
    $args['cat'] = $include_categories;

if ( ! is_search() ) {
    $args['paged'] = $et_paged;
}

if ( '' !== $offset_number && ! empty( $offset_number ) ) {
    $args['offset'] = (int) $offset_number;
}

ob_start();

query_posts( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        $post_format = get_post_format();

        $thumb = '';

        $width = 'on' === $fullwidth ? 1080 : 400;
        $width = (int) apply_filters( 'et_pb_blog_image_width', $width );

        $height = 'on' === $fullwidth ? 675 : 250;
        $height = (int) apply_filters( 'et_pb_blog_image_height', $height );
        $classtext = 'on' === $fullwidth ? 'et_pb_post_main_image' : '';
        $titletext = get_the_title();
        $thumbnail = get_thumbnail( $width, $height, $classtext, $titletext, $titletext, false, 'Blogimage' );
        $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];

        $no_thumb_class = '' === $thumb || 'off' === $show_thumbnail ? ' et_pb_no_thumb' : '';

        if ( in_array( $post_format, array( 'video', 'gallery' ) ) ) {
            $no_thumb_class = '';
        } ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'et_pb_post' . $no_thumb_class ); ?>>

    <?php
        et_divi_post_format_content();

        if ( ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'link', 'audio', 'quote' ) ) ) {
            if ( 'video' === $post_format && false !== ( $first_video = et_get_first_video() ) ) :
                printf(
                    '<div class="et_main_video_container">
                        %1$s
                    </div>',
                    $first_video
                );
            elseif ( 'gallery' === $post_format ) :
                et_gallery_images();
            elseif ( '' !== $thumb && 'on' === $show_thumbnail ) :
                if ( 'on' !== $fullwidth ) echo '<div class="et_pb_image_container">'; ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php print_thumbnail( $thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height ); ?>
                    </a>
            <?php
                if ( 'on' !== $fullwidth ) echo '</div> <!-- .et_pb_image_container -->';
            endif;
        } ?>

    <?php if ( 'off' === $fullwidth || ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'link', 'audio', 'quote', 'gallery' ) ) ) { ?>
        <?php if ( ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'link', 'audio' ) ) ) { ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php
            if ( 'on' === $show_author || 'on' === $show_date || 'on' === $show_categories ) {
                printf( '<p class="post-meta">%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s</p>',
                    (
                        'on' === $show_author
                            ? sprintf( __( 'by %s', 'Divi' ), et_get_the_author_posts_link() )
                            : ''
                    ),
                    (
                        ( 'on' === $show_author && 'on' === $show_date )
                            ? ' | '
                            : ''
                    ),
                    (
                        'on' === $show_date
                            ? sprintf( __( '%s', 'Divi' ), get_the_date( $meta_date ) )
                            : ''
                    ),
                    (
                        (( 'on' === $show_author || 'on' === $show_date ) && 'on' === $show_categories)
                            ? ' | '
                            : ''
                    ),
                    (
                        'on' === $show_categories
                            ? get_the_category_list(', ')
                            : ''
                    )
                );
            }

            if ( 'on' === $show_content ) {
                global $more;
                $more = null;

                the_content( __( 'read more...', 'Divi' ) );
            } else {
                if ( has_excerpt() ) {
                    the_excerpt();
                } else {
                    truncate_post( 270 );
                }
                $more = 'on' == $show_more ? sprintf( ' <a href="%1$s" class="more-link" >%2$s</a>' , esc_url( get_permalink() ), __( 'read more', 'Divi' ) )  : '';
                echo $more;
                } ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php } // 'off' === $fullwidth || ! in_array( $post_format, array( 'link', 'audio', 'quote', 'gallery' ?>

    </article> <!-- .et_pb_post -->

<?php
    } // endwhile

    if ( 'on' === $show_pagination && ! is_search() ) {
        echo '</div> <!-- .et_pb_posts -->';

        $container_is_closed = true;

        if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) )
            wp_pagenavi();
        else
            get_template_part( 'includes/navigation', 'index' );
    }

    wp_reset_query();
} else {
    get_template_part( 'includes/no-results', 'index' );
}

$posts = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

$class = " et_pb_bg_layout_{$background_layout}";

$output = sprintf(
    '<div%5$s class="%1$s%3$s%6$s">
        %2$s
    %4$s',
    ( 'on' === $fullwidth ? 'et_pb_posts' : 'et_pb_blog_grid clearfix' ),
    $posts,
    esc_attr( $class ),
    ( ! $container_is_closed ? '</div> <!-- .et_pb_posts -->' : '' ),
    ( '' !== $module_id ? sprintf( ' id="%1$s"', esc_attr( $module_id ) ) : '' ),
    ( '' !== $module_class ? sprintf( ' %1$s', esc_attr( $module_class ) ) : '' )
);

if ( 'on' !== $fullwidth )
    $output = sprintf( '<div class="et_pb_blog_grid_wrapper">%1$s</div>', $output );

return $output;
}
```

Comment: It is still unclear exactly what you are trying to do. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @tindell I want the title and date of each blog section to be moved to the end of the section through my child theme functions.php. In the code above, I've already moved the `<h2></h2>` area to where I want in the parent functions file, but I don't know how to move around the date (which is the post-meta class)... and I also need to know what exactly to copy into the child theme to keep the changes there. Let me know if you have other questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This big `if` bellow are printing the data ( and other info if needed):

```
if ( 'on' === $show_author || 'on' === $show_date || 'on' === $show_categories ) {
...
}
```

You can move it where you want. :)

Comment: Just a hint: when you trying to find some output in code that you don't know, try finding the tags, class, anything not related with content coming from database ( in this particular case the <p class="post-meta"> is a example)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So would I just copy this `if` statement into the child theme? And what do I move around to get the title and date to the bottom of the `<article>` section?

Comment: That's a great hint too, and I actually did that... but was still confused :)

Comment: You need to move the if statement, Just like like you already did with the title. Cut and paste above or below the h2 and it will be fine.

Comment: If you want to rewrote without messing with the code you already have, i guess you should make your own shortcode (same code, only the few changes) and call it instead of that.

Comment: Moving it worked - thanks!! And yeah, it's just in the parent file now so I need to copy it into the child file, so I don't lose the changes on an update. I'm not sure how much I need to copy to the child file for it to work (none of it is in the child now). Is that where I would create the shortcake again?